# Web browser won't scroll to top when link clicked in smaller window or mobile version.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my website at work I am trying to get the webbrowser to scroll to the tope of the page when in a small screen mode.  According to some answers it should already being doing this anyway.  I have enclosed a copy of the website here:
http://www.synergy-clinics.com/

I believe the code to control navigation is here:

```
var $currentclass = 'currentpanel';
var $currentlinkclass = 'currentlink';
var $class = 'panel';
var $dotclass = '.panel';
//var $body = 'body';
var $body = '#content'
var $downkey = '38';
var $upkey = '40';

//$(function () {
//    $($body).mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
//        var $current = $('div.currentpanel');
//        $next = (delta > 0)?  $current.prev($dotclass) :$next = $current.next($dotclass);
//        if ($next.length) { ChangeCSSClass($current, $next); }
//        event.preventDefault();
//    });
//});

$(function () {
    $($body).keydown(function (event, delta) {
        var $current = $('div.currentpanel');
        if (event.keyCode == $downkey)
        {
            $next = $current.prev($dotclass);
            if ($next.length) { ChangeCSSClass($current, $next); }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == $upkey)
        {
            $next = $current.next($dotclass);
            if ($next.length) { ChangeCSSClass($current, $next); }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function MenuItemClick(SectionName)
{
    var $current = $('div.currentpanel');
    var $next = $('#' + SectionName);
    if ($next != null) { ChangeCSSClass($current, $next); }
    //event.preventDefault();
}

function ChangeCSSClass(Current, New)
{
    $($body).scrollTo(New, 100, { offset: -115 });
    $('#' + Current[0].id + 'Link').removeClass($currentlinkclass);
    $('#' + New[0].id + 'Link').addClass($currentlinkclass);
    Current.removeClass($currentclass);
    Current.addClass($class);
    New.addClass($currentclass);
}
```

I have Identified the scrollto line so it must be around here somewhere, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that a few hours , and finally i did.

can you try that :

http://jsfiddle.net/b4M66/

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();    
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    });    
});​
```

CSS:

```
#toTop { position: fixed; bottom: 50px; right: 30px; width: 84px; background-color: #CCC; cursor: pointer; display: none; }​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toTop">Back to Top</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

The KeyCode functions arent supported on touch screen devices. You have your code based on that. Just try to move that to the touchstart or click function of an element.